# how to display Single Location on mapview in iOs?

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview

How can I display single location with longitude and latitude coordinates on mapview (NOT my current location!)?

I want to display only single Location with these random coordinates- When these coordinates change, the old position on map view has to be removed and replaced with new coordinates? How can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? It's quite simple to add an annotation to `MKMapView` and to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add an annotation:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.title = title
annotation.coordinate = coordinate
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

You can then either remove it with `removeAnnotation` and add a new annotation, or you can animate its moving to a new coordinate:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
}
```

[image: NY to LA]